# Book plugin to record books read and write my own reviews

Tags: plugins, books

I trying to find a plugin where-by I can keep an inventory of all the books I have read (I currently record them in a paper dairy) and also write little reviews for them.  I've seen a few plugins but they don't seem quite right for what I'm after.

Some of the features I was interested in include:

- Categorizing my books by author, genre
- Being able to search my book library
- Being able to write my own review as well as point to official reviews
- Perhaps linking the book to an official page (much like the OpenBook Book Data plugin)

I would use the [OpenBook Book Data](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openbook-book-data/) plugin but that doesn't seem to offer the search and categorizing capabilities I'm after.  Does anyone know of any plugin that offers these features?

Comment: You seem to be seeking more of an out of the box solution then something you could create yourself? If you're familiar with the WP back-end, custom post types are the way to go. Otherwise, I doubt you'll find something so niche.

Comment: Once I've seen a theme for 'books' management, but don't remmember which... I agree with Noel about the "niche". The plugin in fdsa answer will help to build the back-end, but you'll probably have to program a good chunk of the front-end...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the plugin [Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Management](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/). You could create a custom post type 'book' and then add the various custom fields to book.

Comment: hmm, sounds interesting.  I'll take a look.  cheers